# ¿Cómo puedo exportar datos de un formulario de visual Basic a un archivo TXT o de Excel?

Tags: vba, datos

Comunidad. Ojalá se encuentren todos muy bien. Me encuentro haciendo un programa (juego) en Visual Basic. Necesito que los datos que ingresan los jugadores queden registrados en un archivo de texto o en un excel. Los datos que quiero guardar pueden considerarse de dos tipos: (1) el momento en el que se le da click a un botón y a cuál botón se le dió click, y (2) el momento en el que se ingresa una cantidad a un Textbox. Abajo anexo un ejemplo del código un el tercer formulario que estoy empleando, la idea un poco más extendida es que estoy desarrollando una aplicación en donde el usuario tiene un puntaje propio (que se muestra en un label) y un puntaje con su equipo (en otro label), en esa circunstancia el usuario puede ingresar una cantidad en un Textbox y al presionar un botón "invertir" se resta la cantidad que ingresó de sus propios puntos y al mismo tiempo se suma la cantidad ingresada al puntaje del equipo. La duda es ¿Cómo puedo evitar que el usuario invierta cantidades que no tiene? es decir, si tiene 10 puntos y quiere ingresar 20 que el programa lo impida. Hasta ahora sólo he logrado poner un messagebox que le notifique que no tiene la cantidad de puntos, pero la inversión sigue haciéndose y se suman los puntos al equipo y se restan a sus puntos, de modo que el usuario queda con -10 puntos. Abajo anexo la totalidad del código en ese formulario.

```
Public Class Form3
Dim contador_A, contador_B, contador_C As Integer
Dim Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO, Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO, Score_PT_IND_Contrario, Score_PT_IND As Integer
Dim V_T_proteger, V_T_ensayo_entrena, V_T_sustraccion_participante As Integer

Private Sub F_BtnA_CumpleCriterio()
    'Contador de clicks en el botón A

    contador_A = contador_A + 1
    TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_A.Text = contador_A.ToString


    'Si se activa el botón A, entonces se llama la función de cumplimiento de criterio
    If contador_A > 0 Then

        BTN_B.Visible = False
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_B.Visible = False
        LBL_INSTRUCCION_B.Visible = False

        BTN_C.Visible = False
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_C.Visible = False
        LBL_INSTRUCCION_C.Visible = False
    End If
    'Si llega al criterio estipulado entonces
    If contador_A = 10 Then
        Score_PT_IND += 10
        LBL_PT_IND_PARTICIPANTE.Text = Score_PT_IND

        'Poner el msgbox que haga tiempo entre la respuesta del participante y la consecuencia.
        MsgBox("¡Ganaste 10 puntos!")
        'Se restituye la propiedad de visibilidad para los otros botones, contadores y etiquetas de instrucción
        BTN_B.Visible = True
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_B.Visible = True
        LBL_INSTRUCCION_B.Visible = True
        BTN_C.Visible = True
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_C.Visible = True
        LBL_INSTRUCCION_C.Visible = True
        contador_A = 0
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_A.Clear()
        'End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub F_BtnB_CumpleCriterio()

    contador_B = contador_B + 1
    TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_B.Text = contador_B.ToString

    'Si se activa el botón B, entonces:
    If contador_B > 0 Then

        BTN_A.Visible = False
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_A.Visible = False
        LBL_INSTRUCCION_A.Visible = False

        BTN_C.Visible = False
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_C.Visible = False
        LBL_INSTRUCCION_C.Visible = False

    End If

    'Si llega al criterio establecido, entonces:
    If contador_B = 5 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO -= 5
        LBL_PT_IND_CONTRARIO.Text = Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO

        If contador_B = 5 Then
            contador_B = 0
            'Poner el msgbox que haga tiempo entre la respuesta del participante y la consecuencia.
            MsgBox("¡Robaste 5 puntos!")
            'Se restituye la propiedad de visibilidad para los otros botones, contadores y etiquetas de instrucción
            BTN_A.Visible = True
            TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_A.Visible = True
            LBL_INSTRUCCION_A.Visible = True
            BTN_C.Visible = True
            TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_C.Visible = True
            LBL_INSTRUCCION_C.Visible = True
            TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_B.Clear()

        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub F_BtnC_CumpleCriterio()
    contador_C = contador_C + 1
    TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_C.Text = contador_C.ToString

    'Si se presiona el botòn y esto cambia el valor del contador_C, entonces:
    If contador_C > 0 Then

        BTN_B.Visible = False
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_B.Visible = False
        LBL_INSTRUCCION_B.Visible = False

        BTN_A.Visible = False
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_A.Visible = False
        LBL_INSTRUCCION_A.Visible = False

    End If

    'Si llega al criterio establecido, entonces:
    If contador_C = 5 Then
        Timer_Proteccion_20.Enabled = True

        'se desactiva ese botón
        BTN_C.Visible = False
        'Se declara el valor con el que tiene que comenzar y mostrar el contador
        V_T_proteger += 10
        'Poner el msgbox que haga tiempo entre la respuesta del participante y la consecuencia.
        MsgBox("¡Te protegiste durante 20 segundos!")
        'Esto restituye la propiedad de visibilidad para los otros botones, contadores y etiquetas de instrucción
        BTN_B.Visible = True
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_B.Visible = True
        LBL_INSTRUCCION_B.Visible = True
        BTN_A.Visible = True
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_A.Visible = True
        LBL_INSTRUCCION_A.Visible = True
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_C.Clear()

    End If




End Sub
Private Sub F_añadir_en_LBL_PT_EQ_ALIADO()
    LBL_PT_EQ_ALIADO.Text = Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO


    'Esta función controla los momentos en los cuales los "participantes" añaden al monto común
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 10 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 20 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += 5
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 32 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += 15
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 44 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += 6
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 54 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += 20
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 64 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += 7
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 76 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += 25
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 86 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += 8
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 98 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += 30
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 110 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += 9
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 119 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += 35
    End If


End Sub
Private Sub F_añadir_en_LBL_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO()
    LBL_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO.Text = Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO
    'Esta función controla los momentos en los cuales los "CONTRINCANTES" añaden al monto común
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 8 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO += 20
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 18 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO += 30
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 30 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO += 40
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 42 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO += 20
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 52 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO += 30
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 62 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO += 20
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 74 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO += 40
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 84 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO += 50
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 96 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO += 50
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 108 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO += 20
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 117 Then
        Score_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO += 10
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub F_añadir_en_LBL_PT_IND_CONTRARIO()
    LBL_PT_IND_CONTRARIO.Text = Score_PT_IND_Contrario


    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 6 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 16 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 26 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 38 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 50 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 60 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 70 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 72 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 84 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 94 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 104 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 116 Then
        Score_PT_IND_Contrario += 10
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub F_sustraer_participante()
    'El timer que indica el tiempo para la sustracción/provocación del participante
    LBL_T_Sustraccion_Participante.Text = V_T_sustraccion_participante
    V_T_sustraccion_participante = V_T_sustraccion_participante + 1

    'LBL_PT_IND_PARTICIPANTE.Text = Score_PT_IND

    'Aquí van las provocaciones: se sustraen puntos a los XX segundos que dependen de que el timer de la protección
    'esté en ceros
    If V_T_proteger = 0 Then
        If V_T_sustraccion_participante = 10 Then
            If Score_PT_IND > 20 Then
                Score_PT_IND -= 20
                LBL_PT_IND_PARTICIPANTE.Text = Score_PT_IND
            End If
        End If
        'se sustraen puntos a los XX segundos
        If V_T_sustraccion_participante = 20 Then
            If Score_PT_IND > 20 Then
                Score_PT_IND -= 20
                LBL_PT_IND_PARTICIPANTE.Text = Score_PT_IND
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub F_proteger()
    '¿Cómo programar que la protección desactive la sustracción?
    'EJEMPLO:
    'If V_T_proteger > 0 Then
    'F_sustraer_participante()
    'End If
End Sub
Private Sub F_Suma_invertir()
    Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO += Val(TXTBX_INVERSION_PT_ALIADO.Text)
    LBL_PT_EQ_ALIADO.Text = Score_PT_EQ_ALIADO
    LBL_PT_IND_PARTICIPANTE.Text = Score_PT_IND
End Sub
Private Sub F_Resta_invertir()


    Score_PT_IND -= Val(TXTBX_INVERSION_PT_ALIADO.Text)
    LBL_PT_IND_PARTICIPANTE.Text = Score_PT_IND

    If Score_PT_IND < 0 Then

        MsgBox("no tienes suficientes puntos")

    End If


End Sub
'Buscar función que permita usar la variable del tiempo como un contador
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    LBL_SALUDO.Text = "Hola, " + Module1.nombre
    'Esconde el TXTBX para que no pueda invertir
    TXTBX_INVERSION_PT_ALIADO.Visible = False
    'Timer del ensayo de entrenamiento
    Timer_Ensayos_Entrenamiento.Start()
    Timer_Ensayos_Entrenamiento.Enabled = True
    Timer_Ensayos_Entrenamiento.Interval = 1000

    'Timer de la protecciòn
    LBL_T_Proteger.Text = V_T_proteger
    Timer_Proteccion_20.Enabled = False
    Timer_Proteccion_20.Interval = 1000

    'Timer de la sustracciòn
    Timer_sustraccion_Participante.Start()
    Timer_sustraccion_Participante.Enabled = True
    Timer_sustraccion_Participante.Interval = 1000
    'Recordar que el valor INTERVAL es el que asigna cuál es el intervalo de tiempo a asignar, por ejemplo,
    'ahora mismo está en 1000, que equivale a 1 segundo.


    LBL_PT_IND_PARTICIPANTE.Text = Score_PT_IND

End Sub


Private Sub BTN_C_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_C.Click
    F_BtnC_CumpleCriterio()
End Sub

Private Sub BTN_A_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_A.Click
    F_BtnA_CumpleCriterio()
    'En la base de datos poner, Ensayos y su numero. Terminando el 1er ensayo tiene que estar la línea con los datos que se van a necesitar.
    'Poner los datos que voy a necesitar para cada uno de los ensayo discretos en un excel.
    ' Al terminar el primer ensayo poner los datos en el TXT
    'Programar los botones con sus condicionalidades
    '1) ¿El botón de proteger va a sumar más tiempo al reloj?
    'R= no, para impedir que el participante se pase protegido
    '2) El botón 
End Sub


Private Sub BTN_B_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_B.Click
    F_BtnB_CumpleCriterio()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer_Ensayos_Entrenamiento.Tick
    'Con este còdigo se muestra el paso del tiempo de manera ascendente en la etiqueta asignada al timer
    Label_T_Ensayo_Entrenamiento.Text = V_T_ensayo_entrena
    V_T_ensayo_entrena = V_T_ensayo_entrena + 1

    'Impide invertir si no tiene puntos
    If LBL_PT_IND_PARTICIPANTE.Text < 0 Or LBL_PT_IND_PARTICIPANTE.Text = 0 Then
        TXTBX_INVERSION_PT_ALIADO.Visible = False
    End If
    If LBL_PT_IND_PARTICIPANTE.Text > 0 Then
        TXTBX_INVERSION_PT_ALIADO.Visible = True
    End If

    F_añadir_en_LBL_PT_EQ_ALIADO()
    F_añadir_en_LBL_PT_EQ_CONTRARIO()
    F_añadir_en_LBL_PT_IND_CONTRARIO()

    'Si llega a cierta cantidad de TIEMPO entonces se PASA AL SIGUIENTE FORMULARIO
    If V_T_ensayo_entrena = 120 Then
        Form4.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer_sustraccion_Participante_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer_sustraccion_Participante.Tick
    'Con este còdigo se muestra el paso del tiempo de manera ascendente en la etiqueta asignada al timer
    'LBL_T_Sustraccion_Participante.Text = V_T_sustraccion_participante
    ' V_T_sustraccion_participante = V_T_sustraccion_participante + 1

    'Se llama la funciòn asignada al timer, en este caso el de la sustracciòn
    F_sustraer_participante()

    'Detener el timer
    If V_T_sustraccion_participante = 70 Then
        Timer_Proteccion_20.Stop()
    End If

    'Si se llega a 5 el contador, esconde el botòn C
    ' If V_T_sustraccion_participante = 20 Then
    'F_sustraer_participante()
    'End If


    'If V_T_sustraccion_participante = 30 Then
    'F_sustraer_participante()
    'End If


End Sub

Private Sub BTN_INVERSION_PT_ALIADO_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_INVERSION_PT_ALIADO.Click
    F_Suma_invertir()

    F_Resta_invertir()

    TXTBX_INVERSION_PT_ALIADO.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer_Proteccion_20.Tick
    'Con este còdigo se muestra el paso del tiempo de manera descendente  en la etiqueta asignada al timer

    LBL_T_Proteger.Text = V_T_proteger
    V_T_proteger = V_T_proteger - 1
    F_proteger()

    'Detener el timer
    If V_T_proteger < 0 Then
        Timer_Proteccion_20.Stop()
    End If

    'Si se llega a 5 el contador, esconde el botòn C
    If contador_C = 5 Then
        BTN_C.Visible = False
    End If

    If V_T_proteger < 0 Then
        BTN_C.Visible = True
        TXTBX_COUNT_CLICKS_C.Text = 0
        contador_C = 0

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Buenas. ¿Podrías dejar código? ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Anexé una gran parte del código. Espero se entienda. Muchas gracias!